# how to evaluate number between a range of numbers using different variables in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have many pairs of integers like (a,b),(c,d),(e,f) .. so on. I need to check if the value of 1st element lies between a range of 90% to 150% of the 2nd element and print the value as Pass.

The values (a,b) are from different columns of a file for two different times respectively.

File1:`1 12 123 1234-text-1 12345`

File2:`2 23 234 1239-text-1 12347`

```
a="$(find . -name *abc.gz* -mtime 1 | xargs zcat | awk -F"," '{print $4}' | grep "text-1" | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | awk '{print $1}')"

b="$(find . -name *abc.gz* -mtime 10 | xargs zcat | awk -F"," '{print $4}' | | grep "text-1"| awk '{$1=$1;print}' | awk '{print $1}')"

#a=1234
#b=1239

b1="$(bc <<<"${b}*9/10")"
b2="$(bc <<<"${b}*15/10")"

if [ ${a} -ge ${b1} -a ${a} -le ${b2} ];
  then
  echo "PASS"
  else
  echo "FAIL"
fi
```

I need to do it for different text values like 'text-2', 'text-3' etc for different columns of a file $5, $6 etc.

Comment: Are these from different files? Your question is really unclear: please simplify it.

Comment: @Varun : You could pass the text values and column number as a parameter. BTW, it's slightly simpler to extract the column using `cut` instead of `awk`.  Also, since you need to spawn so many processes for this simple task, you might consider writing the whole program in a more efficient programming language, such as Perl, Ruby or Python.

Comment: @Varun : Your approach will fail, if your (unnecessarily complicated) pipe returns more than one value. If you can not exclude this possibility with certainity, I suggest that you check for this. Also note that `$1=$1` is a no-op: You just assign the first field to itself. What's the purpose of this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your whole question, but note that bash cannot do any sort of floating point arithmetic:

```
$ if [ 1234 -ge 1115.1 -a 1234 -le 1858.5 ]; then echo ok; else echo nope; fi
bash: [: 1115.1: integer expression expected
nope
```

You can have bc do the comparisons:

```
check() {
   local result=$(echo "0.9*$2 <= $1 && $1 <= 1.5*$2" | bc)
   (( result == 1 )) && echo OK || echo NO
}
check 1234 1239    # => OK
check 1234 12390   # => NO
```